# Simple python question. How do I make the values in my list read in an input. I know this is prob too basic for u guys but I need to figure this out

Tags: python, list, input

[image: 1]

This is my work and it wont read the items inside my list. What should I do?

Comment: Please paste code and error messages as text, not a screenshot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `if` condition is wrong. You should check if the `bag` is in a lit, `notallowed'.

The error message means, you are trying to check if `['gun', 'knife']` is in `gun`, which is impossible. The error is saying that the left of `in` should be a character (but you used a list), because right of `in` is a string.

```py
bag = input("What is inside your bag?")
notallowed = ['gun', 'knife']

if bag in notallowed: # This line is fixed
    print("now way")
else:
    print("You may pass")
```

The code result:

```py
What is inside your bag?gun
now way  # It prints correctly now.
```

Comment: it actually work bro thanks!

Comment: @FrancoGarcia Happy to help you. If you are satisfied with this answer, please accept this answer so that other people can see this answer is correctly solved your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Should be:

```
if bag in notallowed:
```

Comment: It didn't work bro

Comment: Try add a print to display the value of `bag`